# google CAPTCHA fails on HTTPS works perfectly testing on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I have an issue using the Google CAPTCHA service. I am able to verify the captcha on my system which does not use ssl. When I post the code to my https site all captcha checks fail.

I've seen several questions of stack with the same issue but the posts are all old and they do not fix the problem.

My client code -

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script> 
 .....    
  var challenge= Recaptcha.get_challenge();
  var response = Recaptcha.get_response();
  ...call to server passes above values
```

server code:

```
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = 'myprivatekey';
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ( $privatekey  , $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $chall, $resp);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
 return false;
 } else {
 return true;
 }
```

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015814/recaptcha-not-working-on-https ?

Comment: Yes, I've made all the suggested updates. The verify still fails

Comment: Just checked ajax recaptcha over https - no problems at all. Show why do you think that you are getting negative response and how do you send response and challenge from your page to your php script.

Comment: The return value from check answer is - incorrect-captcha-sol

Comment: You did not do what I asked you. Again, I made the form with Ajax captcha and send the results of captcha by ajax to the php script that validates the data. And found no problems. Show how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.

I was sending the values in a custom header field.

HTTP_USERENTERED_CODE when running on my server the header was passed as HTTP-USERENTERED-CODE
Adding a check for the different format name fixed the issue.