# phpMyAdmin recaptcha https does not work

Tags: https, phpmyadmin, recaptcha

Recaptcha in phpMyAdmin works in http://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php but not  https://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php

Getting the hint from [Recaptcha not working on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015814/recaptcha-not-working-on-https), I changed the default $use_ssl=false to true in  phpMyAdmin/libraries/plugins/auth/recaptchalib.php on line 106.

function recaptcha_get_html ($pubkey, $error = null, $use_ssl = true)

It works!!

Answer (score 0):

try uncommenting

```
extension=open_ssl.
```

in php.ini