# Google Captcha not displaying in GoDaddy secure (https)

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, recaptcha

I'm having an issue where Google's reCaptcha does not appear in my https website and was wondering if anyone else here has encountered/is encountering the same issue and has found a way around it.

In my test environment (localhost), it appears fine and I am able to send and receive the forms. However, upon uploading it to my GoDaddy hosted secure website, the reCaptcha image/div DOES NOT APPEAR and I haven't the slightest idea why.

Please help.

Below are parts of my code (that worked in localhost):

inside "head" tags

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

inside "body" where the recaptcha actually appears:

```
<div class="contact_text">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" id="googlecaptcha"
               data-sitekey="SITEKEYPLACEHOLDER"></div>
   <?php echo "<p class='text-danger col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6'>$errCaptcha</p>";?>
</div>
```

then the "php" part:

```
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEYPLACEHOLDER&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response.success==false){
    $errCaptcha = 'Please check captcha form';
}
```

I based it off of this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

To reiterate, the code/page/form works in my localhost test environment but DOESN'T SHOW when uploaded to my GoDaddy-hosted https website.

I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

**Update:**

Since I nor anyone has any leads on this topic, I opted to go for a different captcha called "secureimage" that adequately fulfilled my needs *for now*. I will keep this question open as I do really want to use Google's captcha because of the intuitive impressive checkbox style captcha.

Hopefully, someone in the near future finds a way.

**Solution:**

Removing the "https:" from the source path properly shows the Google reCaptcha!

```
<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Code block and form now works. Thanks Matthew3k!

Comment: @Hanoncs - I would probably entertain that thought but the hosted site isn't mine. It is a client's. On that note, what made you suggest that? What makes GoDaddy subpar in your opinion?

Comment: Just look around: http://antigodaddy.com/, https://karveldigital.com/why-i-dont-use-godaddy-you-shouldnt-either/, http://www.authormedia.com/6-reasons-authors-should-avoid-godaddy/ I have heard nothing but bad things.

Comment: GoDaddy might be blocking `file_get_contents` to external URLs, can you check the data that should be in `$response`?

Comment: @benpix - that's an interesting thought. However, even if the php submit part is getting blocked, wouldn't the div class of "g-captcha" still show up? I mean, up until that point, the php isn't getting called, only html and css (I guess).

Comment: The captcha would still show, as that's client side javascript and not affected. It's quite common for shared hosts to have such restrictions. Make a test file that does something like this, it doesn't have to be valid data because you should at least get an error back from the URL. `$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEYPLACEHOLDER&response=ABCD&remoteip=ANYIP");` That way you'll know if you're blocked or not. See example responses here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: hmm the issue is the captcha itself doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you made sure to add your site to the list of reCaptcha sites under your account? I would suggest making sure that you entered the name correctly and you are using the correct key for that site.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015814/recaptcha-not-working-on-https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "https:" from the source path.

```
<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I have found this method to be successful for loading cross-domain resources on secure sites.